# "Ум за разум"

Tags: фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "ум за разум заходит"? В чем отличие тут "ума" от "разума"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть версия, что в данном контексте слово "ум" относится в церковнославянскому понятию "умъ", определение чего-то духовного, бестелесного. Разум же означает рациональное, логическое мышление.
Таким образом, поговорка означает, что в голове перепутались чувства с разумом.